# DateTime issue with VB.Net and stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am running SQL Server 2000 and classic asp with vb. I am having a huge headache with a stored procedure which accepts a datetime named start and one named end. I was trying to send  today's date minus one week as date1 to a stored procedure, But I couldn't even get it to send todays date.

```
If date1 = "" Then
    date1 = now() 'eventually want to subtract 7 days from this
End If
If date2 = "" Then
    date2 = now()
End If
```

I have the stored procedure running fine for the other input parameters except for the dates. here is where I am appending the start date.

```
    .Parameters.Append cmdTmp2.CreateParameter("start",135,1,,date1) '129=adChar, 1=adParamInput
    .Parameters.Append cmdTmp2.CreateParameter("end",135,1,,date2) '129=adChar, 1=adParamInput
```

I am recvieing an error: Error converting data type char to datetime

Comment: That looks like VB6 not VB.NET.

Comment: What are the types of `date1` and `date2`?  Are that `Date` or are they `String`?

Comment: VB6 or .NET.  It can't be both...

Comment: I have initialized them in the following manner.

Dim date1, date2

Comment: Yea. Classic ASP doesn't use VB.NET, it uses VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now` would give today's date and time.  Date.Today would give today's date.  `DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-7, Date.Today)` would do 7 days before today.

Edit: What type of parameter is your stored procedure expecting?

Comment: It is expecting a datetime, as specified earlier. "@start datetime"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass an actual `Date` object to the `CreateParameter` method.  Since you do not specify a type when you declare `date1` and `date2`, they could reference any type of object, which complicates things.  The easiest thing to do would be declare them as `Date` type variables, for instance:

```
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
If date1 = Date.MinValue Then
    date1 = Date.Today.AddDays(-7)
End If
If date2 = Date.MinValue Then
    date2 = Date.Today
End If
```

If you do that, it should work fine.  If for some reason you need them to be base object types, then you will have to parse them or cast them to proper `Date` objects (depending on their type) before passing them in.

Comment: Thanks! I like your suggestion however I am getting the following error: Expected end of statement

Comment: On which line?  I suspect it's because my answer assumes VB.NET syntax.